# Tableview subview overlaying UIView subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a UIView subclass that should be 'floating' above TableView that is placing whole screen. UIView subview was displaying as it should when it was setted up in same ViewController as TableView. I tried to make this element reusable so i moved it to separate class of UIView. Now UIView is displaying below TableView. Implementing bringSubviewToFront() or sendSubviewToBack() is not working and nothing is changing.

Here's simplified code:

**UIView class**

```
 class SomeUIView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addSubview(someUIView)
    setupSomeUIView() //autolayout.etc 
    }

    let someUIView: UIView = {
     //here goes customisation
     return UIView
    }

    func setupSomeUIView(){
      someUIView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      someUIView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 7).isActive = true
      someUIView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
      someUIView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -7).isActive = true
      someUIView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 63).isActive = true

    }
```

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
     someTableView = UITableView()       

     someUIView: SomeUIView { return self.view as! SomeUIView}

     ovveride func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.view = SomeUIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
     setupTableView()
     }

     func setupTableView() {
       view.addSubview(searchResultsTableView)
       someTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 70, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
       someTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       someTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
       someTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
       someTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
       someTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
       someTableView.register(SomeCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your `someUIView` is the view onto which the `tableView` is added. So, how can you expect it be on top the `tableView` in the hierarchy? They are not subviews of some view. `tableView` is a subview in `SomeUIView`.

Comment: How can i make someUIView a subview of main viewcontroller view?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
self.view = SomeUIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

That is illegal. You cannot change the view controller’s main view in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: How can i make this up? Put this somewhere else, or do I have to change the code?

Comment: You need to start by showing us real code instead of fake junk that wouldn’t compile in a million years and uses meaningless names for things. Then we will have something to work with.

Comment: Here I excluded only ViewControllers extension where class conforms to TableViewDelegate and I handle number of cells.. etc. and customisation of UIView. All the rest remained the same. How can I make SomeUIView a subview of ViewControllers main view, because i guess that's the point?